# modifying python daemon script, stop does not work

Tags: python, linux, shell, daemon

I'm trying to modify this [example](https://github.com/frdmn/service-daemons/blob/master/centos) using some input from [here](https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/software/pythonlauncher/) as I want only to stop the specific Python app running as a daemon because there will be others as well on the same server running on Python so don't want kill all python scripts...

The server runs the Amazon Linux which I believe is CentOS.

```
USER="root"
APPNAME="myPythonApp1"
APPBIN="/usr/bin/python"
APPARGS="/usr/local/sbin/app1/app.py"
LOGFILE="/var/log/$APPNAME/error.log"
LOCKFILE="/var/lock/subsys/$APPNAME"

LOGPATH=$(dirname $LOGFILE)

prog=$APPBIN

start() {
        [ -x $prog ] || exit 5
        [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
        [ -f $LOGFILE ] || touch $LOGFILE

        echo -n $"Starting $APPNAME: "
        daemon --user=$USER "$APPBIN $APPARGS >>$LOGFILE &"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        echo -n $"Stopping $APPNAME: "
        pid=`ps -ef | grep '[p]ython $APPARGS' | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        echo $pid
        kill $pid
        sleep 1
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}
```

Start works fine, no issue. When I try and stop I get an error:

> kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

If I run from the shell the command to get the pid, it works:

```
ps -ef | grep '[p]ython /usr/local/sbin/app1/app.py' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I get the processid so what am I missing...?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably `echo $pid` is printing a blank …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single-quotes in your grep expression:

```
grep '[p]ython $APPARGS'
```

In single quotes, a variable won't be expanded. You should use double quotes:

```
grep "[p]ython $APPARGS"
```

Comment: Thanks @robert ! Follow up question if I may... when I stop I don't get the OK as when I start... is this because of the python script?

Comment: Hmmm … could it be something to do with the value of `$RETVAL`?

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/service-start-script-doesn't-show-ok-or-failed-820410/

Comment: Indeed... killproc though takes a "/full/path/to/executable" and this means all python daemons will be terminated... :(

Comment: Where there's a will there's a way …

Comment: Managed to do it... details in my follow up post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337798/modifying-python-daemon-script-stop-does-not-return-ok-but-does-kill-the-proce)