# modifying python daemon script, stop does not return OK (but does kill the process)

Tags: python, linux, shell, daemon

Following on from the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336427/modifying-python-daemon-script-stop-does-not-work/30337220?noredirect=1#comment48769500_30337220), the script now start and stops the python script (and only that particular script) correctly but does not report the OK back to the screen...

```
USER="root"
APPNAME="myPythonApp1"
APPBIN="/usr/bin/python"
APPARGS="/usr/local/sbin/app1/app.py"
LOGFILE="/var/log/$APPNAME/error.log"
LOCKFILE="/var/lock/subsys/$APPNAME"

LOGPATH=$(dirname $LOGFILE)

prog=$APPBIN

start() {
        [ -x $prog ] || exit 5
        [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
        [ -f $LOGFILE ] || touch $LOGFILE

        echo -n $"Starting $APPNAME: "
        daemon --user=$USER "$APPBIN $APPARGS >>$LOGFILE &"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        echo -n $"Stopping $APPNAME: "
        pid=`ps -ef | grep "[p]ython $APPARGS" | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        echo $pid
        kill $pid
        sleep 1
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}
```

Starting:

> Starting indigolinkserver:                                 [  OK  ]

Stopping:

> Stopping indigolinkserver:

Within the app.py I have added:

```
[...]
def set_exit_handler(func):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, func)
[...]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def on_exit(sig, func=None):
        #print "exit handler triggered"
        sys.exit(1)

set_exit_handler(on_exit)
```

At command line I get the print (when uncommented) but within the daemon script I get nothing... something is not going back to RETVAL... is it fixable?

There is a [post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/service-start-script-doesn%27t-show-ok-or-failed-820410/) (thanks @robert) about being able only to use killproc with daemons to have this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you are assigning `RETVAL=$?` after `sleep` so it will always have the value "0" unless for some reason `sleep` terminates abnormally ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it to work with the exit handlers so I ended up doing it with .pid files instead...

```
USER="root"
APPNAME="myPythonApp1"
APPBIN="/usr/bin/python"
APPARGS="/usr/local/sbin/app1/app.py"
LOGFILE="/var/log/$APPNAME/error.log"
LOCKFILE="/var/lock/subsys/$APPNAME"

LOGPATH=$(dirname $LOGFILE)

prog=$APPBIN

start() {
        [ -x $prog ] || exit 5
        [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
        [ -f $LOGFILE ] || touch $LOGFILE

        echo -n $"Starting $APPNAME: "
        daemon --user=$USER "$APPBIN $APPARGS >>$LOGFILE &"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        echo -n $"Stopping $APPNAME: "
        pid=`ps -ef | grep "[p]ython $APPARGS" | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        killproc -p /var/run/$APPNAME.pid
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
}
```

and within the python code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = str(os.getpid())
    pidfile = "/var/run/myPythonApp1.pid"

    if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
        print "%s already exists" % pidfile
        #sys.exit()
    else:
    file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)
```